# In what situation a class is not affected to a accessibility level?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop

Pretty straight forward here. I want to know when a class in c# (and probably any oo-language) is okay being neither "public", "private", "protected"...

I am asking this question because when I create a class in Visual studio it generates me a class stub with no accessibility modifier like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace myNamespace
{
    class myClass
    {
    }
}
```

And every time I don't give that much attention to this part of the code and make a reference to it somewhere else and finally run and get a Inconsistent accessibility error.

So in what situation a class can, and maybe should be just "class" and not public or anytyhing? I'm having hard time finding a place where it would be a good thing.

Is there a default accessibility modifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general rule in C# is "the default is as private as you can explicitly declare it". So:

```
namespace Foo
{
    class Bar  // Implicitly internal class Bar
    {
        int x; // Implicitly private int x

        void Baz() {} // Implicitly private void Baz() {}

        class Nested // Implicitly private class Nested
        {
        }
    }
}
```

... you can't declare a top-level (non-nested) class as `private`, but you *can* declare a nested class as private.

The *only* case in which this rule is sort of broken is with properties, where the default for a getter or setter is "the same as the overall property declaration" and you can only specify a *more* restrictive modifier on a getter/setter. For example:

```
internal string Foo { get; private set; }
```

has an internal getter. The overall property follows the first rule, however - so it defaults to being private.

Comment: great clarification and thanks for the exception on the properties!

Answer (score 2):

`internal` is the default if the class is top level.

If it is nested inside another class.. then it is `private`.

See the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

> Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace, internal is the default if no access modifier is specified.
>
> The access level for class members and struct members, including nested classes and structs, is private by default.

Answer (score 0):

From [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx):

> Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can be either public or internal. **Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified.**

(emphasis added) The page goes on to mention default (and other allowed) accessibility for nested classes and members.